# What is the best way to take a small portion of items from a large RealmCollection?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, realm

I'm currently working on a Xamarin.Forms project using Realm 5.1.2. I need to take a collection of RealmObjects, filter them into a smaller set, and convert them to a UI element for displaying data based on each item. On smaller data sets, the implementation I have works well. However, when attempting to do this with a large data set (1,000,000+ items to start, filtered down to ~1000), the app slows down drastically when attempting to convert the filtered objects.

So far, I've attempted to fix this by containing my filtering process to IQueryables and IRealmCollection. I'm aware that instantiating all the objects in my final result is causing the slow down. I'm looking to add a lazy loading method, since not every element will be visible at a time (only loading 10 at a time, and request more as needed). My current implementation is:

Creating the RealmCollection once:

```
var filteredRealmCollection = localRealm.All<Field>()
    .Where(field => field.IndexedId == input.TargetIndexId)  //Use indexed parameter for initial filter
    .Where(field => field.Value == input.TargetValue)  //Take all fields that match the requested filter value
    .AsRealmCollection();
```

Calling for new items as needed:

```
IEnumerable<FieldItemViewModel> GetFieldItemViewModels(int numberToSkip, int numberToTake)
{
    return filteredRealmCollection
        .Skip(numberToSkip)
        .Take(numberToTake)
        .Select(field => new FieldItemViewModel(field)
}
```

The creation of the RealmCollection runs just fine, and if I wait for the whole list to instantiate, it has the correct values. Calling GetFieldItemViewModels also works just fine. But when I try to actually use the returned IEnumerable, the app freezes up until it instantiates the entirety of filteredRealmCollection. I've also attempted to use RealmCollection[index] to get a subset of items, with similar results.

Is there a way to only instantiate the items I've requested using RealmCollection, so that I'm only loading 10 items instead of ~1000? If not, is there a different way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Can I ask you what are you trying to do with FieldItemViewModel? For instance, if you want to show the content of Field in a collection it would be much more convenient to bind the UI to the result of the query.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about [Limiting Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/data-types/collections/#limiting-query-results) (thats the Swift SDK docs but it's the same for the others). Realm results are lazily loaded so those should not have an impact on your app. If you only need 10 at a time, then you would only 'convert' those 10 for display, then dump them when you're done and 'convert' the next 10 as needed. That way you only have 10 in memory at a time which should be easily doable.

Comment: @papafe This logic is being used for displaying a list of data items. The realmCollection and the function I showed above are in a FieldListViewModel class, which controls the overall list structure, manages the list items, etc.  Our old implementation took the query used to make the RealmCollection, converted it to a list of FieldItemViewModels, and bound it to a FieldListView's CollectionView.ItemSource, which uses DataTemplates to convert the FieldItemViewModels into FieldItemViews. With small data, it worked fine, but now that we're dealing with larger data, we need to lazy load our data

Comment: @Jay Yes, I'm trying to leverage Realm's lazy loading. The idea behind GetFieldItemViewModels was that if there's a lazy loaded RealmCollection, the app could just request more items as needed, and only convert those into FieldItemViewModels. The documentation you posted even says to only load the first ten, but my problem is that I don't know of a method to only load a few items at a time. Even with calls to `Skip` and `Take`, or using indexing such as `filteredRealmCollection[0]`, the app evaluates the entirety of the RealmCollection before converting the data for the 10 items requested.

Comment: For clarity 'load the first 10' means 'load the first 10 from the Realm collection into memory'. For example, create an array and then iterate over the first 10 items in the collection and cast them to that array. When the user scrolls (in a list for example) take the next 10 from the collection and re-populate the array. That way you only ever have 10 in memory at a time. Sometimes the old Realm docs state it better than the new go to [Old Realm docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-legacy/docs/swift/latest/) and scroll down to *Limiting results* - that's a Swift example but it's pretty clear.

Comment: This `let dogs = try! Realm().objects(Dog.self)` lazily loads ALL dogs ingto the dogs Results object. Modifying the code in that example a bit, the for loop iterates over the first 5 dogs `for i in 0..<5 {` and then for your case `dogsArray.append(dogs[i])` would only load 5 dogs into the array, occupying memory. If you need need the next 5, nil out the array and `for i in 5..<10 {` etc. You have access to all dogs but only ever load 5 into memory. I think the issue is whenever you use `GetFieldItemViewModels` you're taking ALL of the realm objects and attempting to put them into memory

Comment: @Jay Do you know if there's a difference between Swift and c# regarding this? I just ran a test, and on a collection with 859 items, `var item = filteredRealmCollection[0]` took several minutes to complete. Also, it seems like it's now evaluating the entire result for every iteration of a for loop. `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { items[i] = collection[i]; }` is going much slower than `collection.Take(10)`

Comment: I am not a c# coder but the essence of Realm is the same across platforms. We have some unknowns as with this `var item = filteredRealmCollection[0]` *we* don't know what `filteredRealmCollection` is. Is that a Realm Results object, a Realm List, or something else? Doing this `var oldDogs = realm.All<Dog>()` creates a Realm Lazily Loaded Results object, `oldDogs` and this `let myDog = oldDogs[0]` will be instantaneous. Perhaps you can update your question with very very basic code demonstrating the issue. Be sure to define what the types and structure of any vars you use so we know what it is.

Comment: @Jay is correct saying that Realm works in the same way across different platforms. As he said it would be good if you could include a more complete example, so that we can understand what could be the issue.